# R paired t-test vs. Bayes analysis?

Tags: r, bayesian, t-test

I have a study with one within-subject factor. The data in the two groups are normally distributed. When running a paired t-test, I get a significant effect, t(19)=6.24, p<.001 which supports H1.

When running the equivalent Bayesian analyses, I get a Bayes Factor = .001 which strongly supports H0.

I struggle to reconcile the two conflicting findings. Any help?

Comment: What kind of prior do you assume for the Bayes factor?

Comment: If you get different results, the analyses are obviously not equivalent. You need to explain exactly what you did if you want to give people a chance to know the answer.